# how to Dispose Memory After closing tabitem in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, dispose

I've attached an example. Every time a form is opened
A new tab is added to the tab control
About 30 megabytes of system memory can be added.
And closing the tab, it will not be released memory!
Who can help?

my sample:
http://www.mediafire.com/?j9bk0q4z607ss3s

my post: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/239990.aspx/2/10?Slowly+system+after+a+little+time+

Answer (score 0):

1. Unregister all cross-object event handlers, i.e. handlers handling events of static objects, global objects, ... If the event is raised and handled in your tab, that's ok. These will be automatically GCed.
2. Use memory profiler